# Why getting post back when I am focusing the control in its events?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In asp.net web project I have one form in which I created all controls in one update panel then all control's events are working properly but when I focusing that control in those events at last then why update panel not working? page getting post back.

created textbox control in update panel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>--%>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserId" runat="server" TabIndex="1" Enabled="false" 
                                        ontextchanged="txtUserId_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
    </asp:TextBox></ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

focusing at final in its event.

```
protected void txtUserId_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["UserIdActive"] = "true";
    checkUserName();
    txtUserId.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Please add **relevant pieces of your code** or you question will be closed, because lack of information!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.com. Please read the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: It is because of your textbox autopostback property.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding about the question , please check whether autopostback property is true or false for controls.

If its true,it postbacks.

Thank you.

Comment: if i do it to false then how can fire its event?

Comment: in change events i have to do some operations

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding about the question , please check whether autopostback property is true or false for controls.

If its true,it postbacks.

the events fire even if you make autopostback false.
making it true will reload the page which starts the asp.net cycle from page_load again.

so make it false and check.it fires only the required events.

Thank you.

Comment: autopostback =false not firing the event.